# Visual studio code customize keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

VS Code Version : 1.26.1 (1.26.1)
Mac version : 10.13.6

How to customize keyboard shortcuts in visual studio code?

For example I want to change Rename to **Shift** - **F6** instead of **F2**

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to menu **Preferences** -> **Keyboard Shortcuts**

   - Shortcut in **windows** its <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>
   - Shortcut in **mac** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
2. Search for the command that you are trying to customise short cut
3. Click on the edit button on the side(Pencil symbol)
4. Type your custom keyboard short cut and press **Enter**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for **Windows**:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and the Keyboard Shortcuts page will open.

Instructions for **MacOS**:

The corresponding shortcut is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Normally a new tab with title *Keyboard Shortcuts* will appear. You can modify any shortcut by pressing the edit icon left to the command name and assigning the desired shortcut.

Comment: Since I'm using mac, I ended up in pressing `CMD + K` and `CMD + S`.